# Full screen activity force to adjustPan

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

have some problem with fullscreen activities, in all activitis I use the code below to make it fullscreen.

```
  WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();

    attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;

    getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
```

And in this activies I use

```
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

While in regular activities all working fine, the keyboard jumps to editText, in full screen activities it's not working. Please advice some workaround, tried diferent but they doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was pretty hard to find a solution. Need to replace the code with this. It makes a transparent navigation bar with working adjustpan.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
getWindow ().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_STATUS_BAR);
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```